Angular event.preventDefault() doesn't work on android mobile
here is my code. but it is not working on android browser. Can someone have any solution for it?
const pattern = /^(?!.*[ ]{2})[^*|":<>[\]{}.,?/`~¥£€\\()\u2026₱§';@&$!#%^*_+=0-9-]+$/g;
    
    if (!pattern.test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

i have try with return false, ... but it still not work
